# Play Recompiles Constantly

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Has someone ever seen this before?

The code on my development machine is constantly recompiling in the background; whereas my colleagues are not having this problem. I am new to the project and have been given a new machine which is setup exactly like the others.

The environments are the same, so I shouldn't be having this problem.

I am new to Play and this happens when I am using the following command: "play run"

Interestingly, when I run the code in a virtual machine (running Ubuntu) on my machine I still get the same issue suggesting it is machine related. But what could it be?

Comment: How do you know that it's recompiling? Which files are being recompiled? If you run "play ~run" it keeps monitoring changes in source code and recompiles them automatically. "play run" should compile only once and then just run the app. Are you using any IDE? Perhaps that could be causing backround compilation.

Comment: Background recompilation is considered to be a great advantage of Play compared to J2EE :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a number of issues:

- If the system clock on your computer is in the past compared to some of the source files, or if the timezone on your computer makes the time earlier than some of the jars you were depending on, you will see this.  Touch all the files in the project, eg:

  ```
  find . -exec touch {} \;
  ```
- Sometimes encoding issues can muck up hashing.  Make sure your encoding matches the encoding actually used in the all the source files.
- IDE's can interfere, deleting/modifying files triggering SBT to recompile them.  Close your IDE and see if that helps.

To debug, run `play`, then in the play console, run `compile`, then run `compile` again.  Then run `last`.  A bunch of debugging output will be displayed, at the top of it should be several lists of files, eg modified, added, deleted, deleted products etc.  This will tell you what triggered recompilation, and hopefully will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem. It had to do with the timestamp which was injected in the footer of the footer scala template. I removed it and it worked.